# Using Git/Github with a two person team?

Tags: git, github

I have used git and github personally for a while now.  But, I am going to add another collaborator to the project and need them to be able to work on it as well.

- How can we both be working on files, then push them back to the master?
- How can we both always have the latest changes?
- What is the best way to work with a 2-3 person team with git?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Your repositories are separate and complete copies. As long as your edits don't conflict by line, they will merge automatically. If they do conflict by line, you can sort it out manually when you sync repositories.
- Run a `git pull` before working on a file. Run a `git push` when you put something to the master.
- Github would work just fine. A network share would also be functional when setup as a bare repository. You can also host your own git daemon service.

Answer (score 3):

We are actually looking into this, currently we have our own repo and migrating to github. Our plans are to have the master(main project) and a primary fork. The primary fork will be our 'master' from which the team will collaborate against and will pull and push into. Each of us will clone this primary fork to work against. Once a feature is complete or bug fixed we will merge back into the main project from the primary fork. Not positive that this is the best way, but considering the high level of concurrency between roughly five developers, waiting till code is back into the main project is just not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

On my team, we all work and commit on our own feature branches.  When a person is done with their feature and all of their tests pass, they merge it into master, and run tests again to make sure the merged code didn't break anything. The other members of the team are then responsible for merging in the changes from master at their discretion and equally responsible resolving any conflicts that occur. In practice, merges of master into individual feature branches happens regularly.

I would highly recommend using github as opposed to hosting your own git server, if getting shit done is your priority and not playing at being an admin.

Comment: Doesn't github have privacy issues? i.e., if my code is supposed to be confidential.

Comment: Seeing as it's created by someone who created a Linux, it's not surprising Github is based off of publicity